# label not inline bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show a bootstrap 4 label for a dropdown href alongside some text, here's the current HTML that I've put together:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img src="http://example.org/img/user/user-13.jpg" alt="">
    <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Adam Schwartz</span> 
    <span class="label bg-blue">Free</span> 
    <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

I also have the following CSS that's being applied:

```
.header .navbar-nav>li .dropdown-toggle .label, .header .navbar-nav>li>a .label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 5px;
    display: block;
    background: #00acac;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    padding: .3em .6em;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

But the issue I'm having is that my **label** is not showing inline to the right of the **name** in-between the caret as you can see below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute;` if you want it to flow normally.

When you include the style rules below, you are telling the browser to take the `.label` out of the flow and position it 8px from the top and 5px from the right of the closest parent component in the DOM with that has a `position` set such as relative or absolute.

```
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
right: 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bootstrap Columns`

```css
img {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
 <div class="col-12 mt-3">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle row d-flex align-items-center align-self-center" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <div class="col-1 div-container px-0 mr-4">
    <img src="http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg" class="" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-5 col-sm-3 col-md-2 ml-3 pl-2 pr-0 ml-md-0 pl-md-0 text-left">Adam Schwartz</div>
   <div class="px-2 pl-lg-0 pr-lg-2">Free</div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Please see the live example below.

```css
.dropdown-toggle,
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 300px;
}

.btn-group img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/">
      Adam Schwartz
    <span class="badge badge-primary">Free</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>      
    </button>

  <!--  Add the .dropdown-menu class to a <div> element to actually build the dropdown menu. -->
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```